# Z80 assembly using alternative registers

Tags: assembly, cpu-registers, z80

I tried to write bubble sort for z80 assembly and I found that I need using alternative registers. But the recommended syntax (B′) not work and raise errors. How can I use those registers?

Comment: Ugh, it's been 40 years, do consider the [retro computing site](http://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com) for questions like this.  They are not directly addressable.  You have to use, say, the EXX instruction to force a swap.  Primary useful for fast IRQ service code, not so much for general purpose programming.  If you run out of registers then you'll have to store values to memory.  The stack is the best place.

Comment: Thanks, but this is for my university project and I am forced to deal with old things like this.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/assembly/4802/registers/16904/zilog-z80-registers#t=201703051314568071355  (One of the very few articles I wrote, which accidentally happened to use Z80 as example)

Comment: BTW it's a bit suspicious you ran out of registers for bubble sort, maybe you can use memory for some rarely used values (like initialization between loops), but the inner swapper should fit into registers on Z80 I guess, there's so many of them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are no instructions to use the shadow registers directly.
Instead there is an [instruction `EXX`](http://z80-heaven.wikidot.com/instructions-set:exx) to exchange the normal registers with the shadow registers.

**Give yourself to the dark side**
If you plan to use the shadow registers outside an interrupt handler<sup>1</sup> you must also [disable interrupts](http://z80-heaven.wikidot.com/instructions-set:di) for the duration of using the shadow registers.

Example:

```
di           ;disable interrupts
exx          ;exchange registers BC,DE,HL with BC',DE',and HL'
ld b,8       ;do stuff with the shadow registers
....
exx          ;put the normal registers in charge
ei           ;re-enable interrupts
```

<sup>1</sup>)*Only applies if your system uses the shadow regs in the interrupt handler.*

**Warning**
Do not do lengthy calculations with interrupts disabled, or your system will not be able to react to the external inputs that the interrupt handler processes.

There is also a shadow register for AF: AF'.
You access this like so:

```
ex af,af'    ;exchange af with its shadow register.
```

Note that even though `ex` does not affect the flags per se, `ex af,af'` will exchange the flags register with its shadow.

For more info see: http://z80-heaven.wikidot.com/instructions-set

Note that [bubble sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort) sucks as an algorithm and it ought to be banned.
Please implement [insertion sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) instead.

**Use the stack Luke**
If you do do lengthy processing, then you cannot use the shadow registers and must use the stack instead using [`push`](http://z80-heaven.wikidot.com/instructions-set:push) and [`pop`](http://z80-heaven.wikidot.com/instructions-set:pop).

```
ld b,8              ;normal processing
push bc              ;save bc for later
ld b,9              ;extended processing
... do stuff with bc
pop bc               ;throw away the extended bc and restore the old bc.
```

**…No. There is another.**
If the stack does not cut it for you, you'll have to store values in memory using [`ld`](http://z80-heaven.wikidot.com/instructions-set:ld).

```
ld b,8               ;do stuff with bc
ld (1000),bc         ;store bc for later
ld b,9               ;do other stuff
.....
ld (1002),bc         ;store the extended bc
ld bc,(1000)         ;restore the saved bc
....                 ;continue processing.
```

The nice thing about addressing memory directly is that you don't have to throw values away; the disadvantage is that it runs a bit slower than the stack.

Comment: You must disable interrupts only when the interrupt handler does use the shadow registers. For example on ZX Spectrum the default IM 1 handler from ROM does not use shadow registers, and you can use them freely without `DI`.  Also of course to do anything more complex you usually ended with your own IM 2 handler, so then you have full control which registers are used by interrupt. Plus if you are syncing with VSYNC and have somewhat duration-stable code running each frame, you can tell in which parts it's impossible to get normal IRQ (so only manual request would crash it). DI is overrated. ;)

Comment: About memory storing... with Z80 we also used self-modifying code sometimes: `ld (next_load+1),bc` `next_load: ld bc,12345`, so you don't need to have additional memory (the code did already reserve memory for the value) and load the value back 2x faster for `bc/de` registers. But such technique is strongly discouraged for source-readability reasons, not recommending it, just mentioning it works ok with Z80 (definitely not something to do on modern CPU, in best case will cause huge performance penalty, on some architectures it wouldn't even work correctly if the write would happen too late).